# Admob in flex 4.6 native extensions

Tags: apache-flex, admob, flex-mobile

Has anyone found a way to get a Native Extension running for Admob yet? Or for iAd for that matter?

There seem to be a number of issues with the ANE, with compiling and with the manifest. Has anyone found a way to have it all sorted?

Comment: ARe you asking about issues w/ a specific NativeExtension?  Or are you asking for a Native Extension?  Here is one for AdMob: http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/ Based on my understanding, your best is to wait for Flex/Flash Builder 4.6 to come out b/c it makes using Native Extensions dirt easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't found a working one yet - I was hoping they'd be there. I hope FB 4.6 makes NE's dirt easy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android/
this is base on admob v6 for ios and admob v4.1 for android
and i test it work ok

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an iOS version of this native extension. Probably I'll make and android version and will post it for free. If you need it now please contact me.

Best,
Emil

Update: You can find more information here: http://lancelotmobile.com/blog/admob-ane/